# Restore Partitioning from Clonezilla Backup

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, clonezilla

My HDD has been getting progressively worse.  Latterly, my sda1 EFI partition got deleted; I have created a new partition in the same place, and it is now sda11 (albeit shown at the beginning).

I wish to restore the partitioning as it was... which I believe I can do with my Clonezilla backup; it has the capability/option of restoring the partitioning from the backup.

[Incidentally, Clonezilla considers itself to be unable to restore one partition, in situ, from a backup from more than one disk (which mine is) -- apparently [to me] for no good reason.]

My question is... can I do that [restore the partition*ing*] .other than. within an attempt to restore a partition *using Clonezilla*, please?

Secondarily/in parallel... would that restore the situation that the first partition was sda1, or am I stuck with it now being sda11, please?

Thank you in advance.

```
Edit_01
```

In response to ChanganAuto's comment... I had (Linux) Fedora installed, and then it arbitrarily died; I tried to reinstall it, and it did not seem to be aware that there was anything it could fix; I tried to create a new installation of Fedora in the same place, and it refused; I thought to therefore point it at the EFI in sda1, and it took the liberty of obliterating it; I was not able to restore my backup into that partition (that is, it booted but it complained that the partition had unspecified errors); my attempts to repair the damage resulted in the partition being deleted entirely.  When I tried to create a new partition in the same physical space, it did... but it numbered it 11, not 1.  Does that help?

My question, again, is as follows.  Is there anything I can use, other than Clonezilla, to restore the partitioning scheme, from a Clonezilla backup, onto the drive of which it is a backup?  (...And if I can and do, will it fix the numbering?)

```
Edit_02
```

Just for the sake of it.

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE  
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0  
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   218   184   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       8091  
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       93  
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0  
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0  
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       312  
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0  
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0  
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       83  
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       44  
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   199   199   000    Old_age   Always       -       4658  
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   126   115   000    Old_age   Always       -       26  
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0  
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0  
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0  
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       1  
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
```

Comment: We're stuck with you not making much sense, I'm afraid, unless you [edit] the question and show some data. And what's the point of trying to re-write a failing drive? Replace it and reinstall or recover from backups **in a new drive**.

Comment: Sorry; I appear to have suggested that there is something wrong with the HDD *physically*.  I have no reason (that I am aware of) to suspect that; it is near-new.

Comment: Delete and reinstall. And if your dual-booting with any Windows 8.x or newer, disabling its Fast Startup feature is a MUST! Other than that there's absolutely NO reason for "unspecified errors" in the ESP other than a failing drive.

Comment: In clonezilla have you tried going to restore partition, selecting the image and partition you want to restore?  I remember being able to do that in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [using google] instructions for using sfdisk to write the partition information from my Clonezilla backup.  (I have had to use "--force" and so I rebooted, so I do not have the www address in front of me... and I can not seem to remember nor recreate the search I used [and I neglected to write either of those down].  Sorry about that.)

The command I used is as follows.  [The instructions had something else instead of "/run/media/liveuser/"; your partitioning software will show the path when you mount a partition.]

```
sudo sfdisk --force /dev/sda < /run/media/liveuser/ {myPath} / {MyArchive} /sda-pt.sf
```

I had to use "--force", in spite of closing everything except Firefox.  (I was booted from a USB drive.)

Immediately, it seems to have worked; I have not tried anything yet.

The answer to my other question is that it has indeed returned the first partition to being sda1 instead of [the changed version] sda11.

Thanks everyone for your efforts.  (I have noted ChanganAuto's advice that I may have to give up and try to get it working on a different drive.)

```
Edit_01
```

That's " {MyPath} " and " {MyArchive} "; I added the spaces to make those elements stand out; the path should not have spaces in it (unless there is a space in a user-created name (in which case refer to the relevant manual to see how to represent spaces)).  Example as follows.

```
sudo sfdisk --force /dev/sda < /run/media/liveuser/HDD/Archives/20230613Backup/sda-pt.sf
```

Note that using "--force" is undesirable, and you should reboot immediately if you do use it.

Comment: BTW, you are allowed to tick it after a day.